# jQuery event that fires on css change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

I am using the `.animate` method to move a `div` 100px to the right over 1 second.

So thats 1px every 10ms. Is there an event that would fire after every pixel movement? Or even an event that fires after every 10-20px of movement?

The example above is a simple one, what i will use it for is to track the `left:` property of multiple elements and work out when to display them only if they are in the visible bounds of the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [step function in animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is what you need (you have to scroll a bit down for that)

> The second version of .animate()
>   provides a step option — a callback
>   function that is fired at each step of
>   the animation. This function is useful
>   for enabling custom animation types or
>   altering the animation as it is
>   occurring. It accepts two arguments
>   (now and fx), and this is set to the
>   DOM element being animated.

```
$(something).animate({
  ..... settings...
},
{
  {
  step: function(now, fx) {
    // where your code goes
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you even read the API for [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Examples of using `step` here:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1856-Using-jQuery-s-Animate-Step-Callback-Function-To-Create-Custom-Animations.htm

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fun-with-jquerys-animate/